# Deploying Django project with Gunicorn and nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, ubuntu-server

I am new to django, i would like to know how to set up my django project with nginx and gunicorn. I read this guide: http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/
but it doesn't work for my project.
I think that it is due to the particular structure of my project, that is:

```
├──icecream
│   ├── settings
│   |    ├── __init.py
│   |    ├── base.py
│   |    ├── local.py
│   |    ├── production.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
```

I got this layout from: https://github.com/twoscoops/django-twoscoops-project.
Can anyone help me, please?
thank you

Comment: I use a very similar structure and Michał Kurzyński's guide worked for me. Tell us exactly what is wrong. What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: It seems that it does not manage to find the settings of the project. when i digit: `(myenv) $ gunicorn_django --bind example.com:8001` does not work at all

Comment: Please, edit your post ad show us at least your `gunicorn_start` file and the error message.

Comment: my `gunicorn_start` is https://dpaste.de/xbuQ#L4,10,16 and the error log is: https://dpaste.de/TITD

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I'll just summarize the steps for deploying a django application with nginx & gunicorn here:

#### 1. Install nginx and add this to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

```
server {

  server_name 127.0.0.1 yourhost@example.com;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/domain-access.log;

  location / {
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_connect_timeout 10;
    proxy_read_timeout 10;

    # This line is important as it tells nginx to channel all requests to port 8000.
    # We will later run our wsgi application on this port using gunicorn.
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
  }

}
```

#### 2. Install gunicorn

```
$ pip install gunicorn
```

#### 3. Start your django project using gunicorn and the wsgi.py file

```
$ cd </path/to/djangoproject_subdirectory_with_wsgi.py>

$ gunicorn wsgi -b 127.0.0.1:8000 --pid /tmp/gunicorn.pid --daemon

# --daemon parameter tells gunicorn to run in the background
# So that gunicorn continues to run even if you close your ssh session
# (You cannot remain ssh-ed into your server all the time right!)
```

Please do not use "wsgi.py"; you just have to use wsgi without the ".py" extension when calling gunicorn. This will start your wsgi application in the background.

#### 4. Visit "yourhost@example.com" in your browser

Now your application must be up and running on your instance. Visit:

http://yourhost@example.com/

and see if your application is running. Do not forget to replce *yourhost@example.com* in the above and in the nginx configuration file before.

#### 5. (Optional) Additional Notes

- In Step 1, if confused; remove all existing lines from the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` file and put the above code inside it. (Or delete and create a new blank file and add the code)
- If you are using virtualenv and you did a`pip install gunicorn` inside the virtualenv in Step 2, then run the Step 3 command with respective virtualenv activated.
- The pid of the gunicorn process is stored in /tmp/gunicorn.pid; incase you want to kill the existing gunicorn process and restart it.
- `supervisord` might be used in conjunction which helps in restarting the gunicorn daemon automatically in case it dies due to some reason. This is useful in production environments.

Comment: Why do you point to port 8000 and not the unix socket created by gunicorn?